# How do I create an index of other contracts and their methods?

Tags: proxy-contracts

I want to create a proxy / router contract that stores

1. addresses of other contracts
2. function names of other contracts functionality and
3. accepted parameters in these contracts.
4. ID for each contract

the proxy contract itself will have an AddContract and RemoveContract that adds these parameters to the registry.

Then I want to be able to use this same contract to proxy calls to other contracts. So if somebody calls a smart contract with ID XYZ, with a function myFunction("Here", "is", 123) it would be routed to the address and function of that defined contract under the same ID.

I would like to be able to add contracts after the original proxy creation too and modify them.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: The first question is why? After all, a call through a proxy will be more expensive.

Comment: Lets say I want to do a DAO. People can create a voting proposal within my deployed contract and then say "Upon a YES Vote execute X contract with Y function and Z parameters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be implemented professionally then I suggest to have a look at Augur project, they do all the things you want, they have Factories to instantiate new contracts, and they have proxy functions that do an "exec" of other functions.

This is one example of a call you are looking for:

```
function executeTransaction(address _to, bytes calldata _data, uint256 _value) external returns (bool) {
    require(authorizedProxies[msg.sender]);
    (bool _didSucceed, bytes memory _resultData) = address(_to).call.value(_value)(_data);
    return _didSucceed;
}
```

The code is here:
https://github.com/AugurProject/augur/blob/942b99fd03a513cc7d304123443979a902b4364c/packages/augur-core/src/contracts/AugurWallet.sol#L68

Comment: Very good answer, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Nulik!